# How do i create a semicolon separated excel or csv file from the values of a column in PANDAS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have an excel file, it has one column, "emails"... i need to get the email values from the column and add them to a row separated by a semicolon.

export or save to either an excel or csv. is this possible in pandas?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your email 'values' are particularly. Once getting them into a pandas df, you can output to .csv with a semi colon delimiter using this code

```
df.to_csv(sep=';', index=False)
```